# Galaxy Samsung s6 freezes when opening my app on it, why?

Tags: android, freeze

I don't know why that happens !!! buttons cant be touched. after touching many times it may work . does any body have any idea about it ?
It never happens in any other device. just in Samsung. if it helps I use background threads for getting location continuously .
it happened on three different device of this kind
[you can download the app fro this link](https://logiico.ir/App/Agent)

Comment: Can you check the logs from the phone? That might give you a hint on what’s going on

Comment: I tried yesterday but debugging process was so slow. I will try today then let you know. thx

Comment: I dont know how but the app on that device works fine right now no hanging no freezing ... 
seems the problem solved but a little bit scary :)